# How to colorize individual bar in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot 3D graph with bars, in which every bar is colored with color I choose. I use the command `set(h(1:2), 'facecolor', red);` which grids the x-axis and colors up to two units on x-axis. I want y-axis instead of x-axis? How can I do this in matlab,

Thanks & Regards
sena

Comment: For Matlab (instead of Octave), see Shai's first answer near the bottom of the duplicate question that uses `bar3`

Comment: A [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550095/1714410) to the answer [Dan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614575/how-to-colorize-individual-bar-in-matlab#comment43651468_27614575) refers to.